Error in VMD when trying to visualize MD trajectory
I am trying to load a trajectory, in the form of a .trj file into VMD. VMD loads my inital .xyz molecule fine. But when I try to load into the molecule my .trj file (with Gromacs TRJ trajectory file type), I get an error with this message:
   Info) Finished with coordinate file C:/Users/jason/Music/xtb-6.7.1/bin/dpg10o.xyz.
gromacsplugin) Cannot read header fromm 'C:/Users/jason/Music/xtb-6.7.1/bin/xtb.trj', no error
ERROR) Could not read file C:/Users/jason/Music/xtb-6.7.1/bin/xtb.trj

I'm not sure how to interpret or fix this. I haven't edited my trj file at all, but for context the first few lines look like this
    113
 energy: -16.484252235883 gnorm: 0.039332692881 xtb: 6.7.1pre (5071a88)
C           -4.93012905979644        5.37267512985516        0.36141393604111
C           -3.46038447713503        4.95431942341565        0.39950736100443
C           -3.32678038546024        3.43568034706478        0.27214253497926
O           -5.06938334653434        6.78283856144118        0.43553823108549
H           -5.45097788395057        4.93657744699546        1.22008922328533
H           -5.41680662266953        5.01268181106857       -0.55142422120144
O           -2.86021844183411        5.43876947965073        1.59968749532715
H           -2.93645087179552        5.45635138921215       -0.42936584693961
C           -6.37941964495590        7.23573241027250        0.10877982347234

and it just repeats similarly to this throughout the file.

Can you upload the traj file and xyz file?

I don't know how to upload files here. I can copy paste parts of them if that's sufficient

Just load only the trj file, there is no need to add it to a molecule already loaded (the trj file is just a sequence of xyz files).
